# WebFaultException to pass back an XML message rather than string?

Tags: wcf, exception, faultexception

In my RESTful services layer, any exceptions that bubble up to me are caught as Fault Exceptions. Within that FaultException, there's a custom XML message that contains `<errorNumber>`, `<errorCode>` and a `<message>`. I re-package the exception as a WebFaultException so I can set the HttpStatusCode for the response header to 400, 401, 404, etc.

However, I don't want to use `WebFaultException<string>(string message, HttpStatusCode code)`. I want the message to also be an XML message.

Anyone seen how to set the HttpStatusCode of the response message AND set an XML message? I'm using Fiddler to examine my response headers and any messages that come up from the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to get around this was create a new class `MyException` with simple properties and used `WebFaultException<MyException>` and it works nicely. I found the solution at the following link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankithakur/ExceptionHandlingWCF12282007072617AM/ExceptionHandlingWCF.aspx

Comment: FYI, that link is broken now.